# Why are my keyboard lights not coming on whenever I touch the touchpad?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, keyboard-backlight

I just installed Ubuntu 23.10 and everything's working well, except for the touchpad. Before I installed Ubuntu, I was using Windows 11 and when I touched the touchpad, the keyboard lights always came on. However, it doesn't do so anymore since I installed Ubuntu. How do I fix this?